# JavaFX: TextArea cursor moves back to the first line on new text

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, textarea

I'm having a hard time with `TextArea`'s cursor, it keeps being set to position 0 in the first line, after adding new text to the `Textarea`.

**Problem Background**

I have a `Textarea`, when I add enough text a scroll bar appears to put the new text below the old one. Until here everything is OK, however, the cursor in the `TextArea` comes back to the top which becomes annoying when I have frequent insertions to the `TextArea`.

Here is how I add the new line each time:

```
void writeLog(String str) {
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + str + "\n");
}
```

How can I stop the cursor in the `TextArea` from going back to the first line after each insertion?

Comment: Try with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895597/javafx-after-setting-text-in-textarea-setting-scroll-to-bottom-in-separate-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append to the end of the `TextArea` you can use [`appendText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-) rather than `setText`:

```
textArea.appendText(str + "\n");
```

This will automatically scroll to the bottom and place the caret to the end of the text.

---

**Note:** A little background.

In the code of `TextInputControl`, `appendText` will call `insertText` as `insertText(getLength(), text);` therefore `textArea.appendText(str + "\n");` and `textArea.insertText(textArea.getLength(), str + "\n");` are equal. `insertText` will set the caret position as `insertationPosition + insertedText.getLength()`, that's why the caret is moved to the end.

Comment: This does not work for me.  It is no different than if I call setText.  (JavaFX 15)

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem and I got the solution. I am coding a notepad, where I had to open the text File, on clicking "Open" menu item. Inside another function, I code it.

```
@FXML
private void openaFile(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Stage window=new Stage();
    FileChooser fc=new FileChooser();
    File sf=fc.showOpenDialog(window);
    if(sf!=null){
               FileReader fr=new FileReader(sf);
               Scanner sc=new Scanner(fr);

               while(sc.hasNext()){
                         text.appendText(sc.next());
                         text.appendText("\n");
              }  
    }
```

}

Comment: this is not a dating site ;) Or in other words - no place to make contacts, so removed the link. As the answer: nothing compared to the accepted answer, is there? And nothing in the question that's related to reading a file (which most probably should be done in a background thread, anyway).